# regex doesn't work with data binding

Tags: angularjs, regex, data-binding

I am doing validation with Angular,

```
<div ng-if="field.required !== 'true'">
   <input id="fld-{{field.id}}" name="{{field.id}}" ng-model="$ctrl.configuration[$ctrl.selectedPlatform][field.id]" ng-pattern="{{field.regex}}">
</div>
```

This is the field data:

```
{
  "id": "addItemToHistoryAfterNSeconds",
  "label": "Add Video to History after how many seconds?",
  "type": "string",
  "default": "5",
  "regex": "/^[+]?([0-9]+(?:[\\.][0-9]*)?|\\.[0-9]+)$/"
}
```

So this basically matches numeric value, for testing purpose.

However, the validation doesn't pass, shows ng-invalid.

When I write `ng-patter="/^[+]?([0-9]+(?:[\\.][0-9]*)?|\\.[0-9]+)$/"` directly, the validation pass.

Anyone knows why?

**Update:**

I want to valid only numeric value, so I will be using:

```
/^[+]?([0-9]+(?:[\\.][0-9]*)?|\\.[0-9]+)$/
```

Comment: You may try with `"regex": ".*"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, any ideas for my update?

Comment: Try `"regex": "^[+]?([0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+)$"`. If it works, I guess you already know why it happens so.  Also, try `"regex": /^\+?([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, that does work! Can you explain that in answer so I can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between how regex is defined in the HTML and JS code. If `ng-pattern` allows you to use `"/regex-here/"` notation with single backslashes denoting literal backslashes, JS code does not as you define strings there using C strings (that is, string literals where you may use escape sequences).

There, you may use either a constructor initialization (using a string), or a regex literal.

Remember that you need to use double backslashes in a string literal, and single backslashes in a regex literal to denote a literal backslash (needed for a regex escape).

```
"regex": "^\\+?([0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]*)?|\\.[0-9]+)$"
"regex": /^\+?([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)$/
```

should work.